# Same animation is displayed different in edit/object mode when animated object is selected

Tags: animation, path

I made an animation in the edit-mode and then I noticed that it looks different in the object-mode.
I wonder why there is such a difference, and I have no idea what thats causes.

The problem appears only if I select the animated object.

Here is the animation in the edit-mode:
[image]

And here in the object-mode:
[image]

Maybe it has something to do with the empty objects, or with the empty objects in combiation with the path.
I already tried to change them but that changed nothing at the outcome.

So why is there a difference, and how can I remedy this?

The Blendfile is attached.

[image]

EDIT: If I delete the path the problem is gone. But I need the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are transformations and deformations by modifiers.
Enable **Display Modifier in Edit Mode** on the modifiers to see the modifier effects in edit mode. Optionally also **Adjust cage to modifier result**.

[image]